# How to update the balance with random value (mysql) when a user registers the website?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

For one of my courses, I'm trying to create banking system website using mysqldb and to write the code that make it possible for me to update users balance with random value while registration so the balance will not depend on the user's registration inserted information. i want the value to be inserted to the right spot in the table, only if this spot is null.

i used the code below:

```
$cursor = $MySQLdb->prepare("UPDATE users SET Balance=(Select FLOOR(0+ RAND() * 10000)) WHERE Balance=null AND userID=<userID>;")
```

I hope I was understood.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do `Balance IS null`, instead of = null.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would never put a calculation in a query string ;) 
Also don't overcomplicate the rand() function. Take a look on the docs: [rand() function docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php)
And lastly maybe think about it that is it a good idea to leave it on null? Maybe you could do something like 1 or so. (Only if it not possible for someone to have 1 money!!)
**Do something like:**

```
$balance_variable = $balance_variable = rand(5000, 10000);
$userID_variable = /*specify it somehow*/;

$cursor = $MySQLdb->prepare("UPDATE users SET Balance=? WHERE Balance IS NULL AND userID=?");
$cursor->bind_param('ss', $balance_variable, $userID_variable);
$cursor->execute();
```